# Unable to find app by keyword in AppStore

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, keyword

I'm new in ASO (App Search optimization) and I have added some keywords to my app. However, my app wasn't included to AppStore response to one of the keywords. New version with keywords was published around week ago. Also, I can't find my app by some words in subtitle. I'm using AppFollow to search my apps' position in response. I can't understand why it happens and may be it is regular case. Can AppStore ignore some words or it is problem of AppFollow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apps' subtitle is not public in AppStore. To make it public you have to reach out support.